# How do I get FluidSynth support in VLC on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, vlc-media-player, midi

I'm trying to play a MIDI file on OS X 10.10 Yosemite. I just downloaded the latest version of VLC from the VideoLAN website, and followed [these MIDI instructions](https://wiki.videolan.org/Midi) to look at audio codecs, but FluidSynth doesn't appear in the preferences window. How can I get it?

[image: VLC preferences]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, FluidSynth was [removed](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/9486) not only from the Windows build but also from the OS X build.

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been removed because of [security issues](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/9486).

However, the plugin is part of the VLC source tree so can be built according to [this link](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20101117042611435). (Never tried it myself.)